# this developer name is invalid .provide the developer name for the report that contains the chart in salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, developername

I have a report which is showing fine in Salesforce classic but in salesforce1 it's giving this error

> 'this developer name is invalid .provide the developer name for the report that contains the chart'.

So what is the solution of this problem.